# Firefox: Make thumbnails of https pages not grey?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, https

Firefox now has a new quick dial page like Chrome and Opera. It shows thumbnails of frequently visited pages. However, for some of my pages, the thumbnails are grey (most notably Facebook, and Google sites). I believe this is because they use SSL, and this was recently changed to not display them as a security feature.

Is there a way to make these sites display as thumbnails again, regardless of SSL? Or alternatively, is there a way to customize the thumbnails (like a static logo, or cooler, dynamic tiles like Windows 8 does)?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that this is a fix for the privacy issue but it doesn't have to do with SSL - rather the `Cache-Control: no-store` HTTP header ([bug 754608](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754608)). This header indicates that a page shouldn't be stored on disk and is a hint that it is security-sensitive, so Firefox no longer creates thumbnails here either. Now some sites (including Facebook or Twitter) use the same header for different reasons - Mozilla discusses solutions in [bug 756881](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=756881) without any conclusion so far.

Unfortunately, there seems to be no work-around. You cannot disable this protection and you cannot specify your own thumbnails either. It seems however that in some cases thumbnails simply got lost due to a bug - this should be fixed in Firefox 15 ([bug 744388](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=744388)).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the  [New tab tools add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-tools/) (which alows you to use your own thumbnails) as a workaround.

Comment: Can you add more details about how this add-on solves the OP's problem? It's better to include details instead of only posting a link.